# OpenSSL RSA Public/Private Encryption/Decryption with pkcs12 file

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa, pkcs#12

I am porting a service from C# to C++ - which involves RSA encryption. Using OpenSSL 1.0.2. (I wrote my first line of C++ two weeks ago - so please bear with me.)

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt data - using RSA. Encryption uses a public key which is retrieved by invoking a server via HTTPS (The public key of the SSL certificate is used).

Decryption happens on the server - which loads the private key from a PFX file (PKCS12).

I am having problems with decryption - **error:0407109F:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error**

What am I doing wrong?

**Encryption - getting public key from server (HTTPS)**

```cpp
int MyUtil::EncryptWithPublicKeyRetrievedFromServer(int length, unsigned char*     bytesToEncrypt, unsigned char* output){
    //Get Certificate from server
    boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    ctx.set_default_verify_paths();
    client myClient = client(io_service, ctx);
    auto cert = myClient.GetX509Certificate("www.myHttpsDomain.com");

    //Get public key
    auto key = X509_get_pubkey(cert);
    auto rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(key);

    //Encrypt
    return RSA_public_encrypt(length, bytesToEncrypt, output, rsa,  RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
}
```

**Decryption - using private key**

```cpp
int MyUtil::DecryptWithPrivateKey(int length, unsigned char* bytesToDecrypt, unsigned char *output){
    auto filePath = "C:\\myCertificateWithPrivateAndPublicKey.pfx";
    auto pass = "MySecretPassword";

    FILE *fp;
    EVP_PKEY *pkey;
    X509 *cert;
    STACK_OF(X509) *ca = NULL;
    PKCS12 *p12;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();

    #pragma warning (disable : 4996) //MS complains about fopen
    if (!(fp = fopen(filePath, "rb"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s\n", filePath);
        exit(1);
    }
    p12 = d2i_PKCS12_fp(fp, NULL);
    fclose(fp);
    if (!p12) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading PKCS#12 file\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    //Parse PKCS12 (PFX) file in order to get private key
    if (!PKCS12_parse(p12, pass, &pkey, &cert, &ca)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing PKCS#12 file\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    PKCS12_free(p12);

    //Decrypt
    auto rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pkey);
    int sizeOfDecryptedData;
    if (sizeOfDecryptedData = RSA_private_decrypt(length, bytesToDecrypt, output, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING) == -1)
    {
        auto err = new char;
        ERR_load_crypto_strings();
        ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error encrypting message: %s\n", err);
        //--> error:0407109F:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error
        delete err;
    }


    sk_X509_pop_free(ca, X509_free);
    X509_free(cert);
    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
    fclose(fp);

    return sizeOfDecryptedData;
}
```

I also tried loading the private key through the **PEM** format and then decrypt

```cpp
int MyUtil::DecryptWithPrivateKey(int length, unsigned char* bytesToDecrypt, unsigned char *output){

    char *private_key_file_name = "C:\\privatekey.cer";

    #pragma warning (disable : 4996) //MS complains about fopen
    FILE *fp = fopen(private_key_file_name, "r");
    RSA *rsa = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    fclose(fp);

    if (sizeOfDecryptedData = RSA_private_decrypt(length, bytesToDecrypt, output, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING) == -1)
    {
        auto err = new char;
        ERR_load_crypto_strings();
        ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error encrypting message: %s\n", err);
        //--> error:0407109F:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error
        delete err;
    }

    return decryptedBytes;
}
```

Comment: it seems there's a typo in your encryption code: you write SA_PKCS1_PADDING instead of RSA_PKCS1_PADDING. I'm not sure if this might affect your problem? I'd think your compiler should have warned you about it...

Comment: @xmoex: Sorry about that - it was only a formatting error here on Stack Overflow. Code compiles and runs. I have tried different Paddings as well to no avail.

Comment: thought so... would have been too easy :-) what about adding some error checking to the encryption part?

Comment: I'd try checking with a newly generated key pair which is ascii-hardcoded into your test to ensure there's no other side effects coming from loading or retrieving the key/certificate data (like this: http://hayageek.com/rsa-encryption-decryption-openssl-c/#highlighter_617878)

Comment: Private decryption seems ok to me (at least with PEM formatted key), so i'd look for an issue in the code that fetches the public key. For example i'd compare the key that the code receives with a key from another source like [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16085/how-to-get-public-key-of-a-secure-webpage)